# Parametric normalized Fermat curves (Fermat functions)

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

The normalized Fermat curve is $X^n+Y^n=1$. We have of course infinite possibilities for parametrisation, but the periodicity is a special characteristic here.

E.g. $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ has periodicity, but not $(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2})^2+(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})^2=1$.

Here I am interested in periodic functions for $n:=3$. Be $x\in \mathbb{C}$.

Be $f^\prime(x)=-\frac{g^2}{f}(x)$ (note: pole $x_0$ for $f(x_0)=0$) , $g^\prime(x)=f(x)$, $f(0)=1$ and $g(0)=0$.

=>  $f^3(x)+g^3(x)=1$

Be $\eta$ and $\mu$ such that $f(\eta)=0,\, g(\eta)=1$ and $f(\mu)=g(\mu)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$.

$X^{-1}$ here is used as inverse function for $X$ within a valid value range. After a few transformations one get e.g.

$(\frac{g}{f})^{-1}(x)=\int\limits_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t^3}$,

$g^{-1}(x)=\int\limits_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt[3]{1+t^3}}$,

$f^{-1}(x)=\int\limits_x^1 \frac{tdt}{\sqrt[3]{1+t^3}^2}$,

$\mu=(\frac{g}{f})^{-1}(1)=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{3}\ln 2$,

$\eta=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})\Gamma(\frac{2}{3})}{\Gamma(1)}=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}=2\mu-\frac{1}{3}\ln 4$.

Be $\lambda:=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$.

Note: With the Taylor expansion around 0 for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ one get $f(\lambda x)=f(x)$ and $g(\lambda x)=\lambda g(x)$.

*The addition theorems for $g$ and $f$.*

With
$(\frac{g}{f})^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{3}(\ln(1+x)+\lambda^2\ln(1+\lambda x)+\lambda\ln(1+\lambda^2 x))$
follows 
$(\frac{g}{f})^{-1}(x)+(\frac{g}{f})^{-1}(y)+\frac{1}{3}\ln(1-\frac{3xy}{(1+x)(1+y)})=(\frac{g}{f})^{-1}(\frac{x+y-xy}{1-xy})$

and with $x\to\frac{g}{f}(x)$, $y\to\frac{g}{f}(y)$ and $f^3(z)+g^3(z)=1$ one get

$f(x+y+\frac{1}{3}\ln(1-\frac{3g(x)g(y)}{(f(x)+g(x))(f(y)+g(y))}))=$
$\frac{f(x)f(y)-g(x)g(y)}{\sqrt[3]{(f(x)f(y)-g(x)g(y))^3+(g(x)f(y)+f(x)g(y)-g(x)g(y))^3}}$
and

$g(x+y+\frac{1}{3}\ln(1-\frac{3g(x)g(y)}{(f(x)+g(x))(f(y)+g(y))}))=$
$\frac{g(x)f(y)+f(x)g(y)-g(x)g(y)}{\sqrt[3]{(f(x)f(y)-g(x)g(y))^3+(g(x)f(y)+f(x)g(y)-g(x)g(y))^3}}$

Be $\phi:=\eta+\mu-\frac{1}{3}\ln(-2)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{\ln(-1)}{3}$.

With $x:=\eta$ and $y:=\mu$ one get $g(\phi)=0$ and $f(\phi)=1$.

General: $g(a)=0$ => $g(x+a)=g(x)$ , here: $\Re(a)\ge 0$.

$x:=\lambda a$ and $y:=\lambda^2 a$: $0=g(0)=g(-a)$ , one get $g(\pm a)=0$

QUESTION: *How* can we interpret $\ln(-1)$ here ?

- Does it mean that $g(x+k\cdot\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}+l\cdot\frac{i\pi}{3})=g(x)$ ? $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$, maybe only $k\in\mathbb{N_0}$
- Does $l$ depend on $k$ or are they independent of each other ?

A supplementary question: Has $\frac{g(\phi x)}{\phi x}$ anything to do with $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty (1-(\frac{x}{k})^3)$ ?

EDIT:

Because of the comments below, the double periodicity here has the form

$g(x+k(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}+i(2l+1)\frac{\pi}{3}))=g(x)$

with $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You have partly rediscovered the historical background for theory of elliptic functions (and elliptic integrals) in the case of the elliptic curve $x^3+y^3=1$... Enchanting stuff, but perhaps better suited for MathSE. A slightly different example than the Fermat curve is written up in some course notes at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/complex/10_elliptic.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the hint - but is this a reason to downvote ? I couldn' get the pdf, Proxy error. I know elliptic functions, but have no answer to my question. I am looking for someone, who can handle such problems.

Comment: DIdn't downvote...

Comment: O.k. sorry Paul Garrett. - And to the *unknown person/moderator*: If somebody downvotes, he/she should say why (arguments!).

Comment: Yes, ideally, one might hope for some feedback about downvotes. But, yes, perhaps disappointingly, it should also (in my opinion, and in some others') be ok to downvote anonymously. Sure, this could be abused... But, srsly, all this voting stuff is just a popularity contest, anyway. So don't be put off by it... if this venue provides you worthwhile information. Things here are very rarely as idiotic as many other places on the introweblogs.

Comment: @Paul Garrett: Thanks for your comment! I try to download your pdf-file but I get: "You don't have permission to access /~garrett/m/complex/10_elliptic.pdf on this server.". This is a pity.

Comment: For some reason, my web pages are broken at the moment. Server crashes earlier today, I guess, and various things didn't "come back up" correctly. Math system staff are working on it... hopefully everything will be back up by tomorrow (Wed).

Comment: @Paul Garrett: Thanks a lot for your hint to your interesting website. Your view is how to construct periodic functions. It’s different to mine: My focus is on the construction of addition theorems – independent of periodicity. Therefore I got the problem how to interpret $\ln -1$. I thought about double periodicity (according to Weierstraß) but I still need an argument to substitute $\ln -1$ by a senseful term.

Comment: Inevitably, $\ln (-1)$ must be $\pi i$ plus some integer multiple of $2\pi i$.

Comment: Of course, but I am not sure, that *all* values for $\ln(-1)$ are valid. Maybe I think too complicate here.

Comment: Note: $g(x+k\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}-k(2l+1)\frac{i\pi}{3})=g(x)$

Comment: Yes, _all_ the possible values.

Comment: @Paul Garrett: Thank you very much for your kind support!